# Campo de busqueda struts en formulario

Tags: java, java-8, struts, struts2

tengo algunas dudas sobre struts.
Me dieron un pequeño proyecto en struts java 8, en este formulario filtra por tarjeta de credito o debito pero se agrega un campo que al darle al boton de consultar tiene que aparecer solanamente lo filtrado por nombre.
Para ello no logro entender el codigo de busqueda por tarjeta(Aparecen todas las tarjetas), agregue lo de action pero no entiendo el form, command,bi,dao.

```
<td class="ContenTabla"><div align="left">Nombre:
<html:text styleClass="FormaTabla" value"" name"MulConsultaStockDispositivoSidForm" 
property="" size="30" maxlength="50" id="MulConsultaSotckDispositivoSidForm"/>
```

Este es mi campo, pero no entiendo como hacer que al momento de hacer clic haga consulta a la base para mostrar solamente el nombre que se indique. Si alguien conoce de otra manera practica se lo agradeceria.